# Regex Extract Delete all but Customer Code:

Tags: regex, jedit

I have a long text file and I want to save all the lines that are similar to the following:

`Customer Code: BER17O`

How can I use REGEX to delete all the data except these lines?

Comment: What kind of tool are you using? If you use `grep`, it will be very simple...

Comment: I am using jEdit, which allows me to find and replace with Regular Expressions. Or replace all.  I can use grep, though, but I don't know what that is, if its a linux command, then no :S lol

Comment: It is a Unix/Linux utility. Oh, well. I think you should learn how to use some of them, since they are quite efficient once you get used to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `multiline` option with this `regex`

`^(?!Customer Code: \w+$).*$`

---

**OR**[if you want to be specific]

`^(?!Customer Code: BER17O$).*$`

---

`(?!)` is a negative lookahead which doesnt match the line if the line starts with `Customer Code:` followed by the word!

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked.  I am new to regex, but I guess that would read as everything BUT this (because of the `!` ?)

Comment: Thank you.  I am still learning with the REGEX but It's very powerful and I would love to learn more.  But it seems like a whole language in itself really.

Comment: @Chud37 you can accept or atleast upvote if that has helped you

Comment: @Chud37: Yes, it is a language in itself. It's wise to see that. Regexes are also not a magic bullet that should be used every time you have a problem processing text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting all other stuff, just fetch what you need: `(Customer Code: [A-Z]{3}\d{3})` if its always thrree capital leters followed by three numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`(Customer Code: [^\s]+)`

This code will match "Customer Code: " and all symbols before space-like symbol.

Comment: One Symbol before space - add a quantifier to the brackets ;)